# How to add new file path to environment variable Path in azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, web2py, pyjwt

I am creating azure web app for web2py project, my application uses `jwt` package. Now I want to install [pyjwt package](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to azure app service. After installing it through kudu it installed on some other location which is not in azure app service environment variable.

[image]

> Now either I need to install this package at default location or I
>   need to include `D:\home\python364x64\Script` to environment variable
>   `PATH`.

I don't know how to do any of this approach? It would be really great if someone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About how to add environment variable to azure you could refer to this wiki: [Adding environment variables](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables). You need the `applicationHost.xdt`, put it under `d:\home\site` folder.

The below is a sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
 <system.webServer> 
  <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
   <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <add name="PATH" value="D:\home\python364x64\Scripts;%PATH%" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" 
    xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
   </environmentVariables>
  </runtime> 
 </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: Great I tested and it is working as expected. I was struggling to migrate my project from PythonAnyWhere  to Azure, but stackoverflow really helped to solve difficult problems which were not easy to debug. By the way apologies for late response