# Why python is still version 2.7 after I've installed a python version 3.6 in my Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to install azure-cli in my app service using python pip install but Im getting an error.

```
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 21.1.3 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've tried the recommendation but it does not also work. So I added Python 3.6.4 x64 extension in my app service and installed it. But the console is still using version 2.7.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install an extension on Azure App Service:

[image]

Click add and select the one you would like to have:

[image]

Then accepts condition. After that you need to change a path and this is shown here in [documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples)

It can be done via [Xdt transform](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add name="FOO" value="BAR" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
        <add name="PATH" value="%PATH%;%HOME%\FolderOnPath" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Please check also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058177/how-to-add-directory-to-path-in-azure-python-app-service)

Comment: I've already done that. The app service C: has Python27 and Python36 folder. Should I delete the Python27 ?

Comment: Please check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019#azure-app-service-kudu-console). So they just navigate to the folder where python is installed. I assume that installing pythin doesn't change the PATH. Maybe [this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59790740/2347999)

Comment: That works! I should navigate to the python364 folder and use python.exe.