# "error in click setup command" when deploying a flask app on Azure App Services

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-devops, azure-appservice

I am try to deploy the **flask** app used in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli) onto a **Windows App Service**.

I am deploying the app from an **Azure DevOps** repo, via the **Azure Portal**.

Alas, the logs indicate that the deployment fails.
They send severals warnings (`no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'`) and an error (`error in click setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers`).

What is going on here?

- I can see that the App Services detected `python-2.7` in spite of me having installed the 3.6 extension. Could that be the problem?
- Also, multiple sources (*e.g.* [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/813205/configure-python-on-azure-app-service.html)) suggest using **Linux App Services** when working with Python rather than their Windows counterpart. Is this the problem here?

**EDIT:** thanks to @Deep's suggestion, I was able to add **applicationhost.xtd** to D:\home\site and switch from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6.4.

Comment: As per [Why python is still version 2.7 after I've installed a python version 3.6 in my Azure App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298694/why-python-is-still-version-2-7-after-ive-installed-a-python-version-3-6-in-my), you can verify whether it's properly installed at required location.

Comment: In the portal, it's only available till Python 3.6.4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcaZc.png 

Reference: [How to set up a Python environment on Azure App Service (Windows)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Deep. Thanks to these instructions I was able to add applicationhost.xtd to D:\home\site and switch from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6.4.